# Disk Usage Analyzer on Synology

Tags: hard-drive, network-attached-storage, synology

How can I get an overview of the disk usage on a Synology hard drives like this:
[image: Disk Usage Analyzer]

Comment: Whoops. Should have looked at the source in your post. My company must have recently blocked this image host. I'll delete this idiotic comments in a few minutes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Synology has an App on it's DSM store called Storage Analyzer, which provides a very friendly user interface to view usage by folder, user, file types, duplicates,  etc... It also keeps a history by analyzing periodically...

[image]

Comment: The Storage Analyzer did not exist when the question was created but solves it now in a perfect way.

Answer (score 5):

NCDU is the closest I can find.  Works really well though.  Simple to use as you only have to copy the file to the diskstation, then terminal in and run. Some more instructions:

http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=82232

Comment: Can be installed via "/opt/bin/ipkg install ncdu" - if you have ipkg set up...

Answer (score 3):

Mount the Synology volume from a Linux workstation running Gnome, and run Disk Usage Analyzer on it.

Comment: but than i dont get stuff like: `/volume1/@cloudstation/`

Answer (score 2):

ncdu is now available as a community package, you can install via package manager

See details on https://synocommunity.com

Answer (score 2):

Because the IPKG stuff does not work for me on a DS218+, because the ipgk installes a wrong version of ncurses (needed by ncdu), the most easy way for me is using "docker".

For example: https://hub.docker.com/r/bernadinm/ncdu (there are many more)

- install the container
- docker run -it -v /:/mount bernadinm/ncdu /mount

and you have full functional "ncdu" without any problems and you don´t have 
to install any package installers or mess with your system.